# Difference between sumbool and intuitionnistic disjunction

Tags: coq

According to Coq's documentation

> sumbool is a boolean type equipped with the justification of their value

I thought that was already a property of the disjunction, in the intuitionnistic (or constructive) logic that Coq implements.

For example, to prove an excluded middle `p \/ ~p` in Coq, you have to do actual work, it is not a logical axiom. So a proof of `p \/ q` must either be a proof of `p` or a proof of `q`.

Then why do we need `sumbool p q` ?

**EDIT**

By replacing the tactics by exact proofs, I got more specific error messages. This one is fine :

```
Lemma sumbool_or : forall p q : Prop, sumbool p q -> p \/ q.
Proof.
  exact (fun (p q : Prop) (H : sumbool p  q) =>
           match H with
           | left p0 => or_introl p0
           | right q0 => or_intror q0
           end).
Qed.
```

However this one

```
Lemma or_sumbool : forall p q : Prop, p \/ q -> sumbool p q.
Proof.
  exact (fun (p q : Prop) (H : p \/ q) =>
           match H with
           | or_introl p0 => left p0
           | or_intror q0 => right q0
           end).
Qed.
```

tells me

```
Error:
Incorrect elimination of "H" in the inductive type "or":
the return type has sort "Set" while it should be "Prop".
Elimination of an inductive object of sort Prop
is not allowed on a predicate in sort Set
because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs.
```

I'm a bit surprised. So a primitive like `match` depends on the sort of thing we want to prove ? It looks low-level lambda-calculus though.

Comment: You might want to read CPDT's [Universes chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html).

Comment: The computational behavior of `match` does not depend on the sort of thing we only to prove; only the corresponding typing rule, which tells which uses of `match` are valid, does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sumbool` type lives in Coq's computationally relevant universe `Type` (or `Set`).  In particular, we can write programs using functions that return elements of `{P} + {Q}` (for instance, the standard library's `Nat.eq_dec : forall n m : nat, {n = m} + {n <> m}`, which tests whether two numbers are equal).

Logical disjunction, on the other hand, belongs to the computationally irrelevant universe `Prop`. We cannot perform case analysis on a proof of type `P \/ Q` because Coq was designed to erase proofs when a program is extracted, and such a case analysis might alter the outcome of a computation.  This makes it safe for us, for example, to add the excluded middle axiom `forall P : Prop, P \/ ~ P` without impacting the execution of extracted programs.

It would also be possible to add a strong form of the excluded middle that lives in `Type`: `forall P : Prop, {P} + {~P}`; however, if we use this axiom to write programs, we will not be able to execute them.

Comment: @V.Semeria Think of what is going to happen at runtime. When extracting a program (i.e. erasing all the proofs since you don't need them at runtime) all arguments of type `or A B` can be erased, i.e. those cannot have any influence on program execution. Whereas it's not possible to remove a term of type `sumbool A B`, we can only hope that the extractor would erase the proofs `left` and `right` constructors carry. Essentially `sumbool` should turn into a plain simple `bool` type at runtime (that was a part of my answer I was writing, but Arthur beat me to it :)).

Comment: @V.Semeria Note that the resulting type is`Prop` for `or` and `Set` for `sumbool`. This means you can use terms of `sumbool` type as *data*, but terms of `or` type is for *specification* purposes only. Which one to use depends on what you are trying to achieve. `sumbool` can be used inside the logical world, but `or` can't affect computations. You can prove `Lemma sumbool_to_or P Q : {P} + {Q} -> P \/ Q.`, but not `P \/ Q -> {P} + {Q}`.